# Building gRPC C++ with CMake on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, cmake, grpc

I'm trying to build gRPC (cpp) using CMake, but running into errors. I am able to successfully build gRPC with `make` per the instructions on the [gRPC cpp page](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md). Using `make` is deprecated, but CMake isn't working for me.

After following the instructions for downloading, cloning etc., I go to the "Building with CMake", where it says for Linux/Unix, do this:

```
$ mkdir -p cmake/build
$ cd cmake/build
$ cmake ../..
$ make
```

For me, it fails at the 3rd line (`cmake`). The following is the output:

```
$ cmake ../..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:138 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    cmake/zlib.cmake

< repeats above error for the following .cmake files: cares, protobuf, ssl, gflags, benchmark, address_sorting and nanopb>
```

Those files (`cmake/<package name>.cmake`) don't exist in the `cmake/` directory on my system. I'm not sure what in the CMakeLists.txt file would cause them to appear there.

Researching this issue, I tried various combinations of `cmake` options such as `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`, `-DgRPC_INSTALL=ON`, and `-DgRPC<package_name>_PROVIDER=package` for each of the fails listed above. I always get the same errors. Finally, I tried running the `run_distrib_test_cmake.sh` script. It eventually failed the same way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third party CMake files (e.g. `cmake/zlib.cmake`) do exist in the GitHub repository you cloned (see [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/cmake)). Please be sure your repository finished cloning completely, to include **all** of the submodules, per the gRPC build [documentation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md#linuxunix-using-make):

> Run from grpc directory after cloning the repo with --recursive or updating submodules.
>
> ```
> $ mkdir -p cmake/build
> $ cd cmake/build
> $ cmake ../..
> $ make
> ```

So be sure everything is cloned with:

```
git checkout --recurse-submodules
```

or

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I posted an answer but your answer made me look at my command history. I blindly did the steps you mentioned, but didn't notice that the cmake directory was pulled down as part of the clone. So I probably deleted the cmake dir at some point. My answer is probably mostly a red herring (installing protocolbuf), though the hiccup about golang is real. I'll edit my answer and accept this one.

Answer (score 0):

As @squareskittles points out, the cmake directory is part of the clone. I probably inadvertently deleted and re-created it.

Other than this, the only other thing I had to do which was not mentioned for Linux builds, was to install golang (`sudo apt-get install golang`). This was mentioned as a prerequisite for Windows, but I think it should more accurately be described as a prerequisite for CMake builds, as it seems to be necessary for Linux, CMake builds.